# Azure database performance is very bad

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am facing performance issues with database hosted in azure, if I run same query in my server response time is 4sec but in azure database it takes around 12secs and sometimes timeout.Basically it takes 3X times the response of server hosted in my company environment. We were using Shared plan after that we tried upgrading the plan to S01 Standard and then to Default1 (Basic: 1 Large), but upgrading plan dint make any difference in performance.Can you please help to make the performance faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what query you are trying to run (at least in terms of complexity). Also please elaborate as to how you connect to the azure db. If you do it from within your company's network a proxy etc. could be the issue as well. Possibly bad network connectivity..

Comment: And make sure the DB is running at least roughly in the same area that you reside in.  Never tried it but connecting to a west american db from central asia might take some time.

Comment: "Azure database performance is very bad",these are blanket statements..What you pay is what you get..We have nearly 300GB database runnning on azure premium subscription and we are more than happy

Comment: we also had some databases on basic tier and we used to face issues,but we tuned the queries running on them to minimize DTU usage.You will have to provide more info

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Database charges on performance.  So if you want more performance, you should change to a higher priced performance tier.

What performance level are you currently in?

Also a comparison with your desktop/laptop is an apples to oranges comparison.  A typical laptop has 4  or 6 cores, 4GB or 8GB of memory and more.  Only a larger Premium performance-level could compare to that potential laptop performance.  Lastly your laptop doesn't have any HA available, and SQL DB has a 99.99 SLA.

I hope this helps.